# ClamAV not installed. ClamAV is already installed

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, virtualhost, htpasswd, ubuntu-13.04

Re-Edit:

After lots of Googling, lots of tracing, lots of tinkering with the nginx.conf & /vhosts -

It came down to an error message saying ClamAV was not up to date. 
Running clamscan told me clamscan was not installed. 
Trying to install clamscan told me it *was* already installed. e_e

So, looks like I'm gonna be wiping this server, soon.

Much thanks to everyone that gave their insight.

If anyone knows a legitimate how or why such a thing can happen, I'd be happy to know...

Edit:

I solved this by restarting the server. e_e

If I am not mistaken, this would implicate php-fpm -- right?

However, now that nginx is online and responding to the config changes I make -- I'm getting 403 forbidden and 502 bad gateway on things I had never gotten before. (ISPConfig and PhpMyAdmin, respectively)
Error log says :

```
[error] 9150#0: *7 open() "[...]/ispconfig/[..]/phpmyadmin" failed (13: Permission denied),
```

One link suggests increasing the buffer size - which I tried, does not work -- 
And the other things I found seemed to be irrelevant ---

Thanks again !

---

---

To make a long story short, this all started when I was trying to make an nginx config to add a password to a site. No big deal - I've done it before, no sweat --

However, the configuration was not working with no good reason as to why ---

Well, long story short, after many failed attempts, I finally commented out the line:

```
include sites-enabled/* ;
```

in nginx.conf

Only for the surprise that *everything still works* ---

After making sure Apache wasn't running (it isn't even installed, anymore!) - 
I Googled around to see if I could find anything about a *config* cache on Nginx - but no dice.

So, I've come to you good people, here -- to see if you can lend me any insight on why *everything still works against my best intentions of breaking it*

Strangely enough, nginx continued to work even after running

```
sudo service nginx stop
* Stopping nginx nginx
```

and

```
sudo cat /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

didn't yield anything useful, aside from the "[emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed"

Which it seems I've always gotten - and has never caused problems, before...

Comment: It sounds like nginx isn't _stopping_ for some reason. You should investigate that, and/or kill it manually before restarting.

Comment: It gave me the * Stopping nginx  --- Is there a case where that may not actually be the case?

Answer (score 2):

Have you restarted nginx to apply changes?

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Can you try stopping nginx and check that all processes are stopped, before restarting it:

```
sudo service nginx stop
ps aux|grep nginx # should display no nginx process
sudo service nginx start
```

If you have "[emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80" in logs, check which process is listening to port 80 `netstat -anlp|grep 80` and stop it/ or kill it.

Comment: Yes... I was even going back and forth between reload and restart --

Comment: `reload` is the better option generally since it won't stop an already running nginx instance if the config is faulty. A restart however will stop the running nginx before starting it again so its possible a faulty config file will prevent it from starting. In this case though it sounds like it isn't running at all so a restart is the correct choice.

Comment: @Kyle agree regarding reload, in this case a process is running on port 80 so I think the better is to stop all, checking that all processes are stopped master&workers, then restart nginx to have a clean instance, after the reload should work as expected

Comment: Under further inspection, tripwire and clamav both went MIA-- . So -- some hackery must be at work, here.